# 7 month old kitten and adopted 5 month old won't stop nursing - help?

Tags: cats, feeding

Hi and thanks in advance for any input.  I've read the other threads with similar issues and helpful comments.  We kept the runt of the litter and got a companion for him and his mother.  Buddy is now 7 months old and Luna is 5 months old and they will not stop nursing.  They sneak around, wait for me to leave, run away when I get back.  I can see the wet fur around the nipples and I'm quite sure the milk has long since dried up.  I feed them lots of healthy kitten food, both wet and dry. I tried separating them and at the first opportunity they went right back to it.  Djinni, the mom, can bat Luna away but Buddy seems to be fighting her to nurse.  Any thoughts are welcome.  I'm an accidental cat owner - Djinni showed up pregnant and starving in my yard and... you can guess the rest... Thanks again

Comment: You write that you already read other posts. Which tips of those other posts have you  tried and why don't they solve your problem? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Cats have been dealing with this for eons. I'd let Djinni handle it. You _could_ put something distasteful but harmless on her nipples -- hairball remedy? -- but she'd probably promptly groom it off herself, so you'd be annoying her for little gain.